# What's the probability for the balls and bins problem?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are 5 bins. 
You randomly throw 7 balls into them.
 What is the probability that at least one of the bins has precisely 3 balls in it? 
How to approach this problem? How to find the probability of any 2 bins has precisely 3 balls in it?

Answer (score 1):

Approach for first problem:

Number the bins and for $i=1,2,3,4,5$ let $B_i$ denote the event that bin $i$ has precisely $3$ balls in it.

Then to be found is: $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^5B_i\right)$$

Applying inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find that:$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^5B_i\right)=5P(B_1)-10P(B_1\cap B_2)$$

Comment: How to find $P(B_1 \cup B_2)$?

Comment: You do not need to find $P(B_1\cup B_2)$ but $P(B_1\cap B_2)=P(B_2\mid B_1)P(B_1)$.

Comment: My bad. 
I mean $P(B_1\cap B_2)$
I am not sure my way of calculating is right or wrong.
$C(7,3)*C(4,3)*(1/5)^3*(1/5)^3*(3/5)^1$

Comment: $P(B_1)=C(7,3)p^3q^4$ for $p=1/5$ and $q=4/5$. Further $P(B_2\mid B_1)=C(4,3)r^3s^1$ for $r=1/4$ and $s=3/4$. Under condition $B_1$ there are $4$ balls left and bin 1 is not accessible anymore.